# ImageMagick: lay a partly transparent tile over an image

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I have a wallpaper.jpg (size: 1920x1280) and a partly transparent tile.gif (size: 16x16).

On a website I want to have the tile as a x- and y-repeated overlay over the wallpaper.

Right now, this overlay is realized using CSS. I want to save one request and merge the (repeated) tile.png with the wallpaper.jpg using ImageMagick. The wallpaper.jpg is generated via ImageMagick anyway.

Following the [Documentation of the -tile option](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#tile), I came up with the following command:

```
convert wallpaper.jpg -size 1920x1280 tile:tile.gif -compose over -composite result.jpg
```

The result, however, is a 1920x1280 jpg filled with the tile, but no wallpaper shining through. Instead, the transparent part of the tile seem to be white.

The documentation says:

> If the tile image is partially transparent then a 'Over' "-compose" method will need to be specified.

So what's wrong?

I also tried -flatten instead of -composite... same result.

edit:
I realize, there is also [another -tile option documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#tile). It seems to follow the concept of overloading. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
convert wallpaper.jpg -background none -size 1920x1280 tile:tile.gif -composite result.jpg
```

(you can also add `-compose over`, but that should not make any difference).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will help, but have you tried converting your tile.gif to a 24-bit PNG file with Alpha/Transparency? - Scratch that....

I found some example showing but am unsure about the full command line:

```
composite -tile tile.gif netscape: wallpaper.jpg
```

Source: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#tile

Comment: I also tried that. Even when the tile is a PNG with transparency and the output file is a PNG, too, the result is the repeated tile with white instead of transparency